# How to testflight ios on m1? I still get issue nonzero

Tags: flutter, dart

I get the major problem cause i can't deploy testflight ios, error said nonzero, i've tried to resolve but still error i don't it is minor or major because i new user on m1, let see pict on below :

[image: Err pict]

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because of many reasons. One common solution is to delete Podfile.lock file, Pods directory and .symlinks folder and run pod install again and build it.